# converting long to string errors, with using substring

Tags: java, string, substring, long-integer

I am trying to convert a long to a string and then find a certain number in string based on the Strings index.

I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
String index out of range: 0
  at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source) 
  at TestFile.main(TestFile.java:12)
```

Why does this not work? I thought I understood `substring` but I guess I don't.

Also if I change it to `substring((i-2), (i-1))` I get a number that is very different than the long. But I don't get the errors anymore.

```
import java.util.*;
public class TestFile {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        long hello = 22L;
        // System.out.println(HW3.sumOfDoubleEvenPlace(hello));

        String strLong = Long.toString(hello);
        int i = strLong.length();
        System.out.println(i);

        int temp;
        String strLongcut = strLong.substring((i-2), (i-2));
        temp = Integer.valueOf(strLongcut.charAt(0));
        System.out.println(temp);
     }
}
```

So I just realized that the second part of `substring` is the length of the part I want to take, not an index.

I still cant get the value of my long returned correctly.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: The length of the substring is secondArgument - firstArgument

Answer (score 0):

The `substring` method goes as follows:

```
myString.substring(indexOfFirstCharacterInTheSubstring,
                   indexOfLastCharacterInSubstring + 1);
```

So what you have by making both parameters the same index is creating a substring of length 0, which doesn't even have an index 0 (if did it would be of length >= 1), and thus the error.

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty string (containing no characters) and you try to get the first character from it. It doesn't have a first character (because it has *no* characters), so `charAt` throws an exception.

In `substring`, the first argument is the index where the substring starts, and the second argument is where it ends. (For example, 2 means "before the character at index 2").

In your code, `i` contains 2, so `i-2` is 0. `strLong` contains `"22"`.

You call `"22".substring(0, 0)` which returns the substring starting before the first character (index 0), and ending before the first character.

```
substring starts here
v
 2 2
^
substring ends here
```

Obviously, this contains no characters, so `substring` returns the empty string `""`.